# PHP quick easy to replace characters?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a function that generates a hash and filters out characters:

```
$str  =  base64_encode(md5("mystring"));
$str  =  str_replace( "+", "_", 
             str_replace( "/", "-", 
             str_replace( "=", "x" $str 
         )));
```

What is the "right" way to do this in php?

i.e., is there a cleaner way?

```
// Let "tr()" be an imaginary function
$str  =  base64_encode(md5("mystring"));
$str  =  tr(  "+/=", "_-x",  $str  );
```

Comment: Fixed. We are actually using md5, not base64_encode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple options here, first using [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) properly:

```
$str = str_replace(array('+', '/', '='), array('_', '-', 'x'), $str);
```

And there's also the always-forgotten [strtr](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$str = strtr($str, '+/=', '_-x');
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't know why I couldn't find that function.

Comment: Indeed, I always forget it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays in str_replace like this

```
$replace = Array('+', '/', '=');
$with    = Array('_', '-', 'x');
$str = str_replace($replace, $with, $str);
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [strtr](http://php.net/strtr) with an array.

```
strtr('replace :this value', array(
    ':this' => 'that'
));
```